# Chrome omitting words from my alert box

Tags: google-chrome, coldfusion-9, javascript

I have the following code on a webpage being served by a coldfusion 9 server.

```
alert("Doing this now may result in loss of data")
```

and when I trigger the alert box this is what I see.

> Doing this now may...

I have never even heard of the or seen anything like this, google didn't produce anything of promise either.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in chrome 13. Do you have code that reproduces this? Also was "Doing this now will..." a typo for "Doing this now may..."?

Comment: The really weird part is how changed the word "may" to "will".  Damn Google, always messing with us! :P

Comment: I like the second message better.  It leaves me in delighted suspense.

Comment: Nice catch mike and Jason. Probably should've copy/pasted it.

Comment: Google is just trying to show you what the user actually sees. They read "doing this now may" then just hit ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I was the only one with this issue.  Yes, I had this exact issue six months ago and for the life of me -- two months -- I couldn't figure it out. Eventually, I found a jQuery / JavaScript error that resulted in this issue.

I'm pretty sure the issue had to do with ending JavaScript lines with the appropriate semi-colon EVERYWHERE. Chrome seems to halfway choke on non-perfect JavaScript.

I suggest poring over your JavaScript code and cleaning it up. Maybe removing it from the page and then introducing it back in slowly, testing along the way. This may be a problem if you use plugins though.

Comment: To be fair, every browser chokes on missing semi-colons somewhere. It would be a much better thing if browsers failed on every missing semi-colon in JS, then maybe people would remember to put them in.

Comment: Yes, all browsers choke on different things. The error the poster gets seems to be unique to Chrome though.